# Cannot draw something on a layer with openLayer

Tags: javascript, angular, ionic-framework, openlayers

I am using Ionic to create an app that use openlayer.
I can successfully draw my map (a custom jpeg file) and interact with it. But i'm pulling my hair since yesterday trying to add a marker / icon / draw a simple point on a layer on top of my map.

I've come to a point where there is no error when the code is executed, but it still does'nt draw anything.

Take a look :

```js
 ionViewDidEnter() {
        this.openLayerMap();
    }

    openLayerMap() {
        
        this.map = new Map({
            controls: defaultControls().extend([
                new FullScreen()
            ]),
            interactions: defaultInteractions().extend([
                new DragRotateAndZoom()
            ]),
            target: 'mapId2',
            layers: [
                new ImageLayer({
                    source: new Static({
                        attributions: 'image of office',
                        url: 'assets/images/officePlan.jpg',
                        projection: this.projection,
                        imageExtent:this.extent
                    })
                })
            ],
            view: new View({
                projection: this.projection,
                center: getCenter(this.extent),
                zoom: 2,
                maxZoom: 8
            })
        });
        
        this.map.on('click', (evt) => {
            console.log(evt.coordinate[0], evt.coordinate[1]);
            this.clickOnMap(evt.coordinate[0], evt.coordinate[1]);
        });
    }
    
  public clickOnMap(x: number, y: number) {
    this.AddMarker(x, y);
  }
  
  public AddMarker(x: number, y: number) {

        var feature = new Feature(
            new Point(x, y)
        );

        var iconStyle = new Style({
            image: new Icon(({
                color: '#8959A8',
                crossOrigin: 'anonymous',
                imgSize: [20, 20],
                src: 'assets/images/logo.png'
            }))
        })

        feature.setStyle(iconStyle);

        var vectorSource = new VectorSource({
            features: [feature]
        });

        var vectorLayer = new VectorLayer({
            source: vectorSource
        });

        console.log("add layer");
        console.log(vectorLayer);

        this.map.addLayer(vectorLayer);
    }
```

With this code it's supposed to draw something when i click on the map. All my "console.log" are printing correctly and the map seems to "accept" my layer as there is no error.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RFIjf.png)

I don't understand why it doesn't work, and i already lost so much time :/ 
Please help

Comment: `new Point(x, y)` should be `new Point([x, y])`

Comment: that did not change anything

Comment: can't see anything else obviously wrong, if you create a plunkr/stackblitz it would be a lot easier to diagnose.

Answer (score 1):

your code seems true. please change your Iconstyle definition

```
 public IconStyle = new Style({
     image: new Icon(({
      anchor: [0.5, 46],
      anchorXUnits: 'fraction',
      anchorYUnits: 'pixels',
      opacity: 0.75,
      src: 'http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/icons/red-pushpin.png'
     })),
   text: new Text({
      font: '18px sans-serif',
      fill: new Fill({
      color: [0, 0, 0, 1]
     })     
    })
  });
 var iconFeature = new Feature({
         geometry: new Point([5725221.258222027, 4264433.078145323]),          
         population: 4000,
         rainfall: 500,
         id: -1234567890 //for sample      
       });
       this.vector.getSource().addFeature(iconFeature );       
       iconFeature .setStyle(this.IconStyle);
   }
```